# Best way of removing emoji support from url / slug only

Tags: urls, slug, emoji

Couldn't find anything on the topic.

I guess something could be done with the [`'wp_unique_post_slug'`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_unique_post_slug) filter but how would I go about just removing the emojis from the slug?

I've tried all kinds of things with this filter but can't seem to remove only the emoji part whilst retaining the functionality of WP numbering the slugs `ID-titlecount` (or whatever it is) in case there's nothing left after non unicodes and emojis are stripped.

Has anyone have happened to work with this and have a snippet handy? :)

Comment: Emoji are essentially just letters. Is there a particular problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: We have a network of blogs and when some of our social networkers share the posts in facebook (they use safari) they have had problems. This might ofc just be because they are not that technically literate, but I thought it'd be just easier to make the blogs not have emojis in urls because I dont think they are necessary. So no, no particular reason, just a quality of life thing for me :)